# Ошибка при компиляции: Not sure how to handle update method's return type. Currently the supported return types are void, int or Int

Tags: java, android, android-room

Пытаюсь реализовать метод update с помощью Navigation и Room. Передаю данные имеющие тип Note с фрагмента HomeFragment из RecyclerView на AddNoteFragment. Вот сам класс Note:

```
@Entity
public class Note {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public int id;

public String title;

public String note;

public Note (@NonNull String title, String note){
    this.title = title;
    this.note = note;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int note_id) {
    this.id = note_id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getNote() {
    return note;
}
public void setNote(String note){
    this.note = note;
}
}
```

С действием передаю такой аргумент(файл nav_graph.xml):

```
<argument
        android:name="Note"
        app:argType="com.example.simplenotes.db.Note"
        app:nullable="true"
        android:defaultValue="@null" />
```

В адаптере NotesAdapter передаю значение:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Note n = list.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(n.getTitle());
        holder.note.setText(n.getNote());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HomeFragmentDirections.ActionAddNote action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionAddNote();
            Note note = list.get(position);
            action.setNote(note);
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(action);

        }
    });

}
```

А потом в AddNoteFragment принимаю значение:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    btn_save = (FloatingActionButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    title = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
    note = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edit_text_note);

    if (getArguments() != null){
        AddNoteFragmentArgs args = AddNoteFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments());
        updateNote = args.getNote();
        title.setText(updateNote.title);
        note.setText(updateNote.note);
    }
  }
```

интерфейс NoteDAO:

```
public interface NoteDAO {
@Insert
void addNote(Note note);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Note ORDER BY id DESC")
List<Note> getAllNotes();

@Insert
void addMultipleNotes(Note ... notes);

@Update
Note updateNote(Note note);
}
```

Не запустившись, приложение выдает ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовала:

```
public class Note implements Serializable(){}
```

но ошибка не исчезла.

Если удалить из NoteDAO метод Update, аргумент из NavGraph и код, который отправляет и принимает значение, то приложение запускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

метод с `@Update` должен быть `void` или возвращать `int` (количество обновлённых строк в базе) [Update](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-update)